Using a script to change subscribers status on WiX
Hope i'll make sense since this isn't my forte.
I have a list of names I uploaded to WiX and made a label for, now basically i need to change all those names to have "Unsubscribed" status. But the wix automation (or normal way) doesn't provide a quick way to do it.
Their support tried my chatGPT script which they said could work, but doesn't, however they do not provide "debugging" help. so they recommended I ask here.
Actually chatGPT also says it isn't possible, or at least he says it's not , but suggest a workaround that doesnt work.
This is the script I got now:
import { contacts } from 'wix-crm-backend';

export function updateContactStatus(contactId) {
    return contacts.updateContact(contactId, {
        'customFields': {
            'subscriptionStatus': 'unsubscribed'
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Contact with ID ${contactId} has been unsubscribed.`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error unsubscribing contact ${contactId}:`, error);
    });
}

"This custom field approach will allow you to label contacts as "unsubscribed," even though the native subscriptionStatus field can't be modified directly via Velo at the moment."
I tried to make a script to change status in my WiX contact list to unsubscribed (from mailing list) status
